# Check if Jersey response connection is open

Tags: java, jersey, java-8

I have a test that is using Jersey to make some request to my service. Now after receive a response, I would like to know if connection has been closed from the server side.
Looking the API of the response, I cannot see anything useful.

Here my code

```
  private Response request(HttpMethod method, Entity<String> entity, Invocation.Builder request) {
    try {
        switch (method) {
            case GET:
                return request.get();
            case PUT:
                return request.put(entity);
            case POST:
                return request.post(entity);
            case DELETE:
                return request.delete();
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Method not supported:" + method);
        }
    } catch (ProcessingException e) {
        getContext().setRequestException(e.getCause());
        if (e.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            logger.error("Thread dumping from SocketTimeout");
            ThreadDumper.dumpToFile();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any idea how can I know if my connection is close or open?

Regards.

Comment: You should check your server side logs to see what has happened with each request.  Better yet, add a breakpoint in the server side code and step through a request.

Comment: I need that info for my test.

Comment: What do you mean by this comment?

Comment: I update the question. I have a bbd test where after finish all the request becuase, that test is the server which close the connection because a timeout, I want to prove that the server is really closing the connections properly.